# How to get the Radio button values from PDF form using PDFbox (C#)

Tags: c#, java, pdf, pdfbox

How to get the Radio button values from PDF form using PDFbox (C#)

In Java :

```
     doc = PDDocument.load("C:\\Users\\347702\\Desktop\\sample_form.pdf");
            List pages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
            PDAcroForm form = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
            List FieldTypes =  form.getFields();
            PDField pdfFields;

            for (int i = 0; i <  FieldTypes.size(); i++) {

              pdfFields = (PDField) ((List) FieldTypes).get(i);
              if (pdfFields instanceof PDRadioCollection) 
                 {
                    String iAsString = Integer.toString(k);
                    System.out.println(iAsString);
                    type = "RadioButton";
                    System.out.println("Radio Button" + "   "
                            + pdfFields.getFullyQualifiedName() + "  ");

                    List kids = pdfFields.getKids();
                    for (Object kid : kids) {
                          if (kid instanceof PDCheckbox) {
                          PDCheckbox checkbox = (PDCheckbox) kid;
                          String Name = checkbox.getOnValue();
                          System.out.println(Name);
                          }
                    }
```

The above java code has been successfully working (successfully returns the children of Radiobuttons) but when the same logic is been implemented in c# its not running as expected

below is my c# code :

```
                else if (pdfFields is PDRadioCollection)
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Radio Button" + "   "
                            + pdfFields.getFullyQualifiedName() + "  ");

                  List kids = pdfFields.getKids();
                    System.Console.WriteLine(kids);

                   for (int w = 0; w < kids.size(); w++)
                   {
                       kids.get(w);
                       System.Console.WriteLine(kids.get(w));  ---- > Return null 

                       System.Console.WriteLine(kids.get(w).ToString()); -- > Return null
                   }  

                }
```

Can any help out in this please
Thanks

Comment: C# - under List kids it holds the child value .. but when i try to print that particular value it fails to do so , it returns null

Answer (score 0):

At last got it work : here it is :: 
C#  : Need to type case with IEnumerable :

```
                else if (pdfFields is PDRadioCollection)
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Radio Button" + "   "
                            + pdfFields.getFullyQualifiedName() + "  ");

                    System.Collections.IEnumerable kids = (System.Collections.IEnumerable)pdfFields.getKids();
                    System.Console.WriteLine(kids);

                    foreach (object kid in kids)
                    {
                        PDCheckbox checkbox = (PDCheckbox)kid;
                         checkbox.check();
                    }
```